# How to allocate sample size to gain most power on a two stage analysis?

Tags: sample-size, genetics, statistical-power

In stage 1 we test many SNPs, in stage 2 we try to confirm these SNPs. Usually we start with less sample, but then it's hard to detect a signal. For example, if we can afford 3000 samples, how to allocate these 3000 people in two stages?

Comment: All I can say right now is that you're probably going to need some sort of pilot study. Could you describe your independent and dependent variables and what "confirming" is?